# How to use 'BatchGetItem' for the NodeJS AWS-SDK for DynamoDB

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get items out of a DynamoDB table using the Node JS AWS-SDK. The function `getItem` is working fine but `BatchGetItem` is harder to use.

I use the official documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Client.html#batchGetItem-property

I am looking for examples on how to use this function correctly, but I can't find any. The code I wrote is:

```
var params = {

"RequestItems" : {
    "Keys" : [
      {"HashKeyElement" : { "N" : "1000" } },
      {"HashKeyElement" : { "N" : "1001" } }
    ]
  }
}

db.client.batchGetItem(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log('error: '+ err);
  console.log(jsDump.parse(data));
});
```

I get a `SerializationException: Start of list found where not expected` error but as far as my NodeJS and JSON expertise goes, my syntax is correct. But it's confusing:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchGetItems.html

In that syntax example, you have to provide the table name.

Comment: Hello, have you got your syntax to work, can you please share your solution?  thanks!  Maybe you can pastebin your getItem and getBatchItem.  Thanks!!!

Comment: For anyone who comes here using js in the browser, note you need batchGet not batchGetItem

Answer (score 18):

I used the dynamo db client version... after an hour of research I managed to make it work...

```
var params = {

RequestItems: { // map of TableName to list of Key to get from each table
    Music: {
        Keys: [ // a list of primary key value maps
            {
                Artist: 'No One You Know',
                SongTitle:'Call Me Today'
                // ... more key attributes, if the primary key is hash/range
            },
            // ... more keys to get from this table ...
        ],
        AttributesToGet: [ // option (attributes to retrieve from this table)
            'AlbumTitle',
            // ... more attribute names ...
        ],
        ConsistentRead: false, // optional (true | false)
    },
    // ... more tables and keys ...
},
ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | TOTAL | INDEXES)
};
docClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

Comment: So for js in the browser it seems you need batchGet but for node you need batchGetItem. I was trying batchGetItem from the browser and got  "Uncaught TypeError: docClient.batchGetItem is not a function". Couldn't find this in the docs.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh the batchget of the documentclient returns the attributes of one or more items from one or more tables by delegating to AWS.DynamoDB.batchGetItem().

Answer (score 11):

I feel your pain... AWS documentation is confusing at best. I think it's caused by aging infrastructure and bad technical writing. The nodejs and JSON syntax used by the SDK reminds me of XML structure.

Anyway, I managed to get the BatchGetItem to work after a whole hour. The params should look like below:

```
{
    "RequestItems": {
        "<TableName>": {
            "Keys": [
                {"<HashKeyName>": {"<type>":"<hash key value>"}},
                {"<HashKeyName>": {"<type>":"<hash key value>"}},
                {"<HashKeyName>": {"<type>":"<hash key value>"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you're missing table name.  You want this:

```
var params = {

"RequestItems" : {
    "TableName": {
      "Keys" : [
        {"HashKeyElement" : { "N" : "1000" } },
        {"HashKeyElement" : { "N" : "1001" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the solutions here and none of them worked for me, which likely means the NodeJS library has gotten an update. Referencing their better written [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html), you should be able to make a request like so:

```
var params = {
  RequestItems: {
    'Table-1': {
      Keys: [
        {
           HashKey: 'haskey',
           NumberRangeKey: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    'Table-2': {
      Keys: [
        { foo: 'bar' },
      ]
    }
  }
};

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

Specifically, providing the type is no longer necessary.

Comment: This is because some of the users were using the plain dynamoDb client, you are using the documentClient

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.client.batchGetItem(
{"RequestItems":{
     "TableName":{
           "Keys":[
               {"HashKeyElement"  : {"N":"1000"}},
               {"HashKeyElement"  : {"N":"1001"}}
           ]
       }
    }
}, function(err, result){ //handle error and result here  });
```

Comment: not working for me...  can you please pastebin a sample that works?  :)  thanks a ton!

Comment: suppose if your tableName is 'Cluster', you can write-- http://pastebin.com/5eVaVALQ      if you still face problem, show me your code snippet.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work like that. See my answer below

Comment: it works for me, and your answer is similar all others.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the correct answer should be:

```
var params = {
    "RequestItems": {
        "<table_name>": {
           "Keys": [
                {"HashKeyElement" : { "N" : "1000" } },
                {"HashKeyElement" : { "N" : "1001" } }
           ]
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's untested though:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "tableName",
    RequestItems : {
        Keys : [
            {
                HashKeyElement : { N : "1000" } 
            },
            {
                HashKeyElement : { N : "1001" } 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```